# Why is R row extraction slower on large sparse Matrix than when dividing it into smaller pieces and then extracting?

Tags: r, loops, time, extract, sparse-matrix

I am working with a 19089 x 9432 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix" (let's call it `M`), and I have to extract each row to perform some calculations on it. I do this with a loop, so at each iteration I have to do something like `currentrow <- M[i,]` to apply the body of the loop on it. The calculations are very time consuming so I want to optimize it as much as possible, and I realized that if I first divide my matrix in small pieces (`M[1:100,]`, `M[101:200,]`, etc...), and that I do a loop on each of those smaller matrices (therefore calling `currentrow <- current_smallM[i,]` at each iteration), the loop is much more faster.

Here is a code example that I run to reproduce this :

```
library(Matrix)

N = 10000
M = 5000

# Creation of the large matrix (of class dgCMatrix)
largeMatrix <- Matrix(rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), byrow = TRUE, nrow = N, sparse = TRUE)


# We take into account the time for the creation of the smaller matrix, and then calculate the time to allocate the 200 rows to a variable
start.time = Sys.time()
smallMatrix = largeMatrix[100:200,]
for (i in 1:100){
    test <- smallMatrix[i,]
}
end.time = Sys.time()
print(end.time - start.time) # 0.47 secs


# Same allocations but working on the large matrix
start.time = Sys.time()
for (i in 100:200){
    test <- largeMatrix[i,]
}
end.time = Sys.time()
print(end.time - start.time) # 18.44 secs
```

You can see that the time difference is really huge... So I am really wondering :

- Why is this happening?
- Is there a more efficient way to store my data than dividing my matrix in smaller pieces?

Interestingly, I tested the same code with a `matrix` object (using `largeMatrix <- matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), N, M)`), and the results were totally different : 0.06 secs for the divided matrix, and 0.04 secs for the large matrix, so I am really wondering what is different with the sparse representation.

Note: I found a quite similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56997363/why-is-numpy-subtraction-slower-on-one-large-matrix-m-than-when-dividing-m-i) but it was with a different language, and (I think that) the solution does not apply here because it was due to an implicite type conversion, whereas here I am just extracting a row.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[dgCMatrix is a compressed sparse **column** format](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix/versions/1.3-4/topics/dgCMatrix-class). It has an `indptr` array that's got X entries where X is the number of columns in the matrix, and an `index` array that identifies the location of each non-zero value, which has N entries where N is the number of non-zero values in the array.

What this means is that every time you want to slice it by **row** it needs to traverse the entire `index` array and look for values that are within the range you want to slice. Using this `smallMatrix = largeMatrix[100:200,]` slices the array into a smaller array where the `index` array is much smaller, and can therefore be traversed more quickly.

Your real problem is that you're trying to get rows out of a data structure that gives you very inefficient slicing for rows and very efficient slicing for columns.

Comment: Also note that in OP's example, `Matrix(rnorm(N*M,mean=0,sd=1), *)` is not actually sparse, it's a dense matrix stored in sparse format. So any kind of extraction is going to be less efficient than using a regular dense format.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was exactly the explanation I was looking for!